# T-SQL: Reducing LEFT OUTER joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, distinct

Is there a better and easier way of doing this?  Suppose I have 500+ groups.  It takes a lot of joins to accomplish that.  In the example below, I only have 3 LEFT OUTER joins, so it's relatively easy.  If there is a better way to model this, without these weird joins, that might be neat to see as well (maybe having a mapping table / bridge table)?

```
SELECT
     [user].id,
     '2010-01-01' AS begin_date,
     group_a.source AS group_a_id,
     group_b.source AS group_b_id,
     group_c.source AS group_c_id
FROM
    (select distinct id FROM [user]) [user]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [group] group_a ON user.id = group_a.user_id and group_a.type in ('1', '2', '5')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [group] group_b ON user.id = group_b.user_id and group_b.type = '3'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [group] group_c ON user.id = group_c.user_id and group_c.type = '4'
```

Comment: "Suppose I have 500+ groups"  Are you suggesting you want 500+ columns to show a user's enrollment in all groups?  Might I suggest not pivoting this.

Comment: What would the SQL look like if we did a pivot?  But we still have various type values per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you looking for this?

```
SELECT
     [user].id,
     '2010-01-01' AS begin_date,
     CASE WHEN group_a.type = '1'
               OR group_a.type = '2'
               OR group_a.type = '5' THEN group_a.source END AS group_a_id,
     CASE WHEN group_a.type = '3' THEN group_a.source END AS group_b_id,
     CASE WHEN group_a.type = '4' THEN group_a.source END AS group_c_id
FROM
    (select distinct id FROM [user]) [user]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [group] group_a ON user.id = group_a.user_id
```

Comment: I agree with Hamlet's answer. You could talk this a step further an incorporate a convention based on the group type or create a crosswalk table.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT
     [user].id,
     '2010-01-01' AS begin_date,
     CASE WHEN group_a.type = '1'
               OR group_a.type = '2'
               OR group_a.type = '5' THEN group_a.source END AS group_a_id,
     CASE WHEN group_a.type = '3' THEN group_a.source END AS group_b_id,
     CASE WHEN group_a.type = '4' THEN group_a.source END AS group_c_id
FROM
    (select distinct id FROM [user]) [user]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [group] group_a ON user.id = group_a.user_id
```